# OS Luna(AMD64) hangs while booting

Tags: luna

While booting the Elementary logo glows, then mouse pointer are displayed and glowing hangs. After 10-15 seconds HDD indicator stops blinking.

When I enter "Recovery mode" and then chose "Resume" - the system boots OK, but is in low resolution.

I think the problem must be to do with the Graphics - I have a notebook with Intel + nVidia, but I uninstalled the nVidia drivers because of trouble using them.

What is wrong with the normal boot that safe boot fixes?